# progressive (continuous)

Tags: verbs, tenses

I'm reviewing a paper about pain, the author writes: "chronic pain is developed in many patients"; what they mean is "chronic pain develops in many patients."

What is a proper grammatical explanation of this correction?

Comment: Maybe what the author really means is  something like "in many patients, minor discomfort [or "seemingly temporary pain" or some other prior symptom] develops into chronic pain." The easy way to explain the point of the revision is that it identifies **what** develops into **what**, by recasting the original passive construction as an active construction. But your revision doesn't really address the patients' prior state; it simply treats pain as developing on its own—out of nowhere, as it were.

Answer (score 2):

They are two different syntactic constructions, and they mean different things in medicine. *Develops* is the active voice, present tense, third person singular of the verb *to develop*, and it's used for the progression of a disease or symptoms:

For instance, from a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=1sWk1GYCvKoC&pg=PA496&lpg=PA496&dq=chronic%20pain%20develops&source=bl&ots=E4R4UWxc-F&sig=zh_B-3JG-Iwgftydk5mRGHm71hQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf8r-fioHRAhVBSCYKHWkKCwo4ChDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=chronic%20pain%20develops&f=false) on rehab medicine:

> The amount of anxiety generated and possibly pain seems to be more influenced by the setting in which **the pain develops** rather than personality variables

They're talking about the influence of the physical environment on the growth or course of a patient's pain.

*Developed*, on the other hand, is the past participle of the same verb, and it shows up as a predicative adjectival complement, describing the subject of a sentence, as in this example from the journal [*Pain*](http://journals.lww.com/pain/Abstract/1992/04000/Chronic_pain_induces_a_paradoxical_increase_in.6.aspx):

> The increase of GH [growth hormone] secretion, at a stage of the illness when chronic pain **is** well **developed**, raises ... questions....

The meaning here is "is present or made manifest". (Ironically, *well* in this instance means *well-along* or acute.)

Comment: I agree, *is developed* describes a state of being and implies some criteria have been met. *Develops* describes a trend towards that state, or an increasing percentage of a sample that has reached that state. Care is needed to distinguish between, say, the percentage of participants who fully meet the criteria, and trends in the aggregate scores among participants.